# Outlook 2010 - displaying trk-srv-001 when opening a mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

when opening a mail, i got the below pop-up

[image]

after the pop-up (it took about 15 seconds or so), the mail was opened.

Anyone out there knows what this means?

It was only with 1 mail.

TIA

Comment: Any futher details? Anythins special in that mail? What is your setup?

Comment: Is this email from someone you know? If so, contact them to find out what they've embedded into the email. Otherwise, delete the email and do not allow it to connect.

Answer (score 0):

There is something embedded in the email that is trying to automatically connect to an external resource. When it fails, it opens the email.